# What is the angular way to have a variable in a service automatically update when a datepicker in a directive is updated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to use a datepicker to select a date and then to have it manipulated in a service in order to generate more dates.

I can retrieve a variable from a service and assign the datepicker value to it, but I can't get the value in the service to update when the datepicker is updated. What is the best angular way to do this?

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/p0YYKJGnvFNskRWgE8n7?p=preview)

```
app.service('calculationDataService', function () {
  this.firstDate = new Date();
});

app.directive('datePicker', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'date-picker.html',
        controller: function($scope, calculationDataService){
            $scope.today = function() {
                $scope.dt = new Date();
            };
            calculationDataService.firstDate = $scope.dt;
            $scope.today();

            $scope.clear = function () {
                $scope.dt = null;
            };

                [...]

        },
        controllerAs: 'pickers'
    };
```

Comment: Theres no code in your plunker that updates any of the service's variables other than when the controller for the `date-picker` directive is created (`calculationDataService.firstDate = $scope.dt;`). What did you want updated in the service when the picker is updated?

Comment: I want firstDate in calculationDataService to show the same value as dt (the date selected in the popup as the popup date is changed by the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign in the controller:

```
$scope.dataService = calculationDataService;
```

and then update the value like

```
$scope.dataService.firstDate = $scope.dt;
```

EDIT

Anyway i see the order is not correct.

you are assigning the startDate property o your servie to undefined as the function is run after the assignation.

You should run $scope.today() one line above

Comment: Do you mean I have to assign in the controller that is inside the datepicker Directive or in the Holidays controller? When I try to put it inside the datepicker Directive, it still doesn't update the values: http://plnkr.co/edit/fkSqcJ4RgYWFdaws9b7L?p=preview Do I need two-way databinding to automatically update it?

Comment: @CarbonandH20 putting it into the controller makes your binding in the view so you dont have to use the service itself. did you assign a value to $today prior to assigning startDAte. As i see you have to call $scope.today(before calculationDataService.firstDate = $scope.dt;)

Comment: I made a simpler setup: http://plnkr.co/edit/MvIw4Z8obWYlIpdiyxVZ?p=preview. All I want to do is have "Controller 2 number" automatically update when "Controller 1 number" updates. Is there a way to do this without broadcasting or watching?

Answer (score 0):

I needed Santiago Rebella's solution. However, to update the date after each update of the datepicker, I also needed an ng-change in the html that ran $scope.dataService.firstDate = $scope.dt.